# page break not working in phpdocx library

Tags: phpdocx

I am using PHPDocx library.Basically I'm having an issue with page-break Here is my code

```
    $html_body .= 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry';$html_body .= 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry';
```

i just want to break page so that both the paragraph appear on different page.
Please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using embedHTML() method the only way you can achieve this, is separating you html code, and adding an use addBreak() method between. Something like this:

```
require_once '../../../classes/CreateDocx.inc';

$docx = new CreateDocx();

$paragraph1 = '<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and type setting industry</p>';
$paragraph2 = '</br><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>';

$docx->embedHTML($paragraph1);

$docx->addBreak(array('type' => 'page'));

$docx->embedHTML($paragraph2);

$docx->createDocx('example_embedHTML_1');
```

Comment: I have an issue for page break,not for line.Indeed,line break working perfectly.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, maybe this can help you out :)